# Filter the records from table which are having count of distinct country codes at least three out of four country code columns

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle

I have a small query

```
+----+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| ID | Country CodeR | CountryCodeB | CountryCodeBR | CountryCodeF |
+----+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
|  1 | US            | US           | US            | UK           |
|  2 | US            | UK           | US            | PK           |
|  3 | US            | UK           | PK            | IND          |
+----+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
```

from above table
Filter the records which are having count of distinct country codes columns at least three out of four country code columns from the above table

From the above table I need result should be like below

```
+----+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
| ID | Country CodeR | CountryCodeB | CountryCodeBR | CountryCodeF |
+----+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
|    |               |              |               |              |
|  2 | US            | UK           | US            | PK           |
|  3 | US            | UK           | PK            | IND          |
+----+---------------+--------------+---------------+--------------+
```

Comment: Please choose whether this is mysql or oracle

Comment: Tim, I dunno what you did, but your edit made things worse than my edit (rolled back)

Comment: Please read & act on [ask] and [help] and hits googling 'stackexchange homework'.

Comment: I dunno if this is homework, it looks like an unpivot, followed by a grouped having, followed by a pivot, to me - that's probably a bit beyond homework!

Comment: This kind of problem is symptomatic of poor design. If it was me, I’d probably have 3 columns: group_id, country_code, type. If the column order is important in your example, then I’d have a fourth column, which might be a surrogate primary key.

Answer (score 3):

Your current data structure makes your query difficult, because the count distinct function operates over *rows*, not columns.  One approach is to convert your data to tall format and then aggregate by `ID`:

```
SELECT t1.*
FROM yourTable t1
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT ID
    FROM
    (
        SELECT ID, CountryCodeR AS CountryCode FROM yourTable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ID, CountryCodeB FROM yourTable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ID, CountryCodeBR FROM yourTable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT ID, CountryCodeF FROM yourTable
    ) t
    GROUP BY ID
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT CountryCode) >= 3
) t2
    ON t1.ID = t2.ID;
```

The above is probably the best you can do on MySQL.  If you were using Oracle, then you would have things like unpivot and CTEs to make for a nicer looking query.

### Demo

Answer (score 0):

```
with tbl as(

select  1 ID,'US' CountryCodeR,'US' CountryCodeB,'US' CountryCodeBR,'UK' 
CountryCodef from dual

union all           

select  2 ID,'US' CountryCodeR,'UK' CountryCodeB,'US' CountryCodeBR,'PK' CountryCodef from dual

union all

select  3 ID,'US' CountryCodeR,'UK' CountryCodeB,'PK' CountryCodeBR,'IND' CountryCodef from dual

)

select t.id,t.CountryCodeR,t.CountryCodeb,t.CountryCodebR,t.CountryCodef from tbl t

join (

select id,CountryCodeB cc from tbl

union all

select id,CountryCodeBr  from tbl

union all

select id,CountryCodeF  from tbl

)s on s.id=t.id

group by t.id,t.CountryCodeR,t.CountryCodeb,t.CountryCodebR,t.CountryCodef

having count (distinct s.cc)=3
```

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of ways of doing it without resorting to pivoting the table and self-joining:

In Oracle, you can put the items into a collection and then use `SET()` to get the unique items and `CARDINALITY` to get the size of the collection:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/57dd9/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE TABLE_NAME(
  ID,
  CountryCodeR,
  CountryCodeB,
  CountryCodeBR,
  CountryCodeF
) As
SELECT 1, 'US', 'US', 'US', 'UK' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 2, 'US', 'UK', 'US', 'PK' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 3, 'US', 'UK', 'PK', 'IND' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 4, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 5, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 6, 'A', 'B', 'A', 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 7, 'A', 'A', 'C', 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 8, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 9, 'A', 'B', 'B', 'D' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 10, 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 11, 'A', 'B', 'B', 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 12, 'A', 'B', 'A', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 13, 'A', 'A', 'C', 'C' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 14, 'A', 'A', 'A', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 15, 'A', 'A', 'B', 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 16, 'A', 'B', 'A', 'A' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 17, 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 18, 'A', 'A', 'A', 'A' FROM DUAL
/

CREATE TYPE StringList IS TABLE OF VARCHAR2(5)
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  CARDINALITY(
         SET(
           StringList(
             CountryCodeR,
             CountryCodeB,
             CountryCodeBR,
             CountryCodeF
           )
         )
       ) >= 3
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/57dd9/1/0)**:

```
| ID | COUNTRYCODER | COUNTRYCODEB | COUNTRYCODEBR | COUNTRYCODEF |
|----|--------------|--------------|---------------|--------------|
|  2 |           US |           UK |            US |           PK |
|  3 |           US |           UK |            PK |          IND |
|  4 |            A |            B |             C |            D |
|  5 |            A |            B |             C |            A |
|  6 |            A |            B |             A |            D |
|  7 |            A |            A |             C |            D |
|  8 |            A |            B |             C |            B |
|  9 |            A |            B |             B |            D |
| 10 |            A |            B |             C |            C |
```

**Query 2**:

You can also use multiple `CASE` statements:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table_name
WHERE  CASE
       WHEN CountryCodeR IN ( CountryCodeB, CountryCodeBR, CountryCodeF )
       THEN 1 ELSE 0
       END
       +
       CASE
       WHEN CountryCodeB IN ( CountryCodeBR, CountryCodeF )
       THEN 1 ELSE 0
       END
       +
       CASE
       WHEN CountryCodeBR IN ( CountryCodeF )
       THEN 1 ELSE 0
       END
       <= 1
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/57dd9/1/1)**:

```
| ID | COUNTRYCODER | COUNTRYCODEB | COUNTRYCODEBR | COUNTRYCODEF |
|----|--------------|--------------|---------------|--------------|
|  2 |           US |           UK |            US |           PK |
|  3 |           US |           UK |            PK |          IND |
|  4 |            A |            B |             C |            D |
|  5 |            A |            B |             C |            A |
|  6 |            A |            B |             A |            D |
|  7 |            A |            A |             C |            D |
|  8 |            A |            B |             C |            B |
|  9 |            A |            B |             B |            D |
| 10 |            A |            B |             C |            C |
```

Which also works in MySQL - [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/1e6e67/1)